# Tornado AsyncHTTPClient performance degradation

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado

**Setup:** Python 2.7.15, Tornado 5.1

I have a web-server machine that handles ~40 `/recommend` requests per second. 
The average response time is 25ms, but there's a big divergence (some requests can take more than 500ms).

Each request generates between 1-8 Elasticsearch queries (HTTP requests) internally.
Each Elasticsearch query can take between 1-150ms.

The Elasticsearch requests are handled synchronously via [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

The goal is to reduce the i/o waiting time (queries to Elasticsearch) and handle more requests per second so I can reduce the number of machines.
One thing is unacceptable - I don't want to increase the average handle time (25ms).

I found some tornado-elasticsearch implementations on the web, but since I need to use only one endpoint to Elasticsearch (`/_search`) I am trying to do that alone.

Below there's a degenerated implementation of my web-server. With the same load (~40 request per second) the average request response time increased to **200ms**!

Digging in, I see that the internal async handle time (queries to Elasticsearch) is not stable and the time takes to each `fetch` call might be different, and the total average (in `ab` load test) is high.

I'm using `ab` to simulate the load and measure it internally by printing the current `fetch` handle time, average `fetch` handle time and maximum handle time.
When doing one request at a time (concurrency 1):
`ab -p es-query-rcom.txt  -T application/json -n 1000 -c 1 -k 'http://localhost:5002/recommend'`

my prints looks like: `[avg req_time: 3, dur: 3] [current req_time: 2, dur: 3] [max req_time: 125, dur: 125] reqs: 8000`

But when I try to increase the concurrency (up to 8): `ab -p es-query-rcom.txt  -T application/json -n 1000 -c 8 -k 'http://localhost:5002/recommend'`

now my prints looks like: `[avg req_time: 6, dur: 13] [current req_time: 4, dur: 4] [max req_time: 73, dur: 84] reqs: 8000`

The average req is now **x2 slower** (or **x4** by my measurements)!
What do I miss here? why do I see this degradation?

**web_server.py:**

```
import tornado
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.options import define, options
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from web_handler import WebHandler

SERVICE_NAME = 'web_server'
NUM_OF_PROCESSES = 1


class Statistics(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.total_requests = 0
        self.total_requests_time = 0
        self.total_duration = 0
        self.max_time = 0
        self.max_duration = 0


class RcomService(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'initializing RcomService...'
        AsyncHTTPClient.configure("tornado.curl_httpclient.CurlAsyncHTTPClient", max_clients=3)
        self.stats = Statistics()

    def start(self, port):
        define("port", default=port, type=int)
        db = self.get_db(self.stats)
        routes = self.generate_routes(db)
        app = tornado.web.Application(routes)
        http_server = HTTPServer(app, xheaders=True)
        http_server.bind(options.port)
        http_server.start(NUM_OF_PROCESSES)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

    @staticmethod
    def generate_routes(db):
        return [
            (r"/recommend", WebHandler, dict(db=db))
        ]

    @staticmethod
    def get_db(stats):
        return {
            'stats': stats
        }


def main():
    port = 5002
    print('starting %s on port %s', SERVICE_NAME, port)

    rcom_service = RcomService()
    rcom_service.start(port)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**web_handler.py:**

```
import time
import ujson
from tornado import gen
from tornado.gen import coroutine
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.web import RequestHandler


class WebHandler(RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, db):
        self.stats = db['stats']

    @coroutine
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = yield self.wrapper_innear_loop([{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}])  # dummy queries (empty)
        self.write({
            'res': result
        })

    @coroutine
    def wrapper_innear_loop(self, queries):
        result = []
        for q in queries:  # queries are performed serially 
            res = yield self.async_fetch_gen(q)
            result.append(res)
        raise gen.Return(result)

    @coroutine
    def async_fetch_gen(self, query):
        url = 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search'

        headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        }

        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        start_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        response = yield http_client.fetch(url, method='POST', body=ujson.dumps(query), headers=headers)
        end_time = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
        duration = end_time - start_time
        body = ujson.loads(response.body)
        request_time = int(round(response.request_time * 1000))
        self.stats.total_requests += 1
        self.stats.total_requests_time += request_time
        self.stats.total_duration += duration
        if self.stats.max_time < request_time:
            self.stats.max_time = request_time
        if self.stats.max_duration < duration:
            self.stats.max_duration = duration
        duration_avg = self.stats.total_duration / self.stats.total_requests
        time_avg = self.stats.total_requests_time / self.stats.total_requests
        print "[avg req_time: " + str(time_avg) + ", dur: " + str(duration_avg) + \
              "] [current req_time: " + str(request_time) + ", dur: " + str(duration) + "] [max req_time: " + \
              str(self.stats.max_time) + ", dur: " + str(self.stats.max_duration) + "] reqs: " + \
              str(self.stats.total_requests)
        raise gen.Return(body)
```

I tried to play a bit with the async class (`Simple` vs `curl`), the `max_clients` size, but I don't understand what is the best tune in my case.
But

Comment: My bet is that it's an elastic's, not AsyncHTTP's degradation. Have you tried monitoring elastic's performance?

Comment: @Fian yes, it's not, I printed the `took` in ms of every query respond

Answer (score 0):

Increased time may be because with concurrency==1, CPU was under-utilized and with c==8 it's 100%+ utilized and is unable to catch up with all requests. Example, abstract CPU can process 1000 operations/sec, to send a request it takes 50 CPU ops and to read a request result it takes 50 CPU ops too. When you have 5 RPS your CPU is 50% utilized and average request time is 50 ms (to send a req.) + request time + 50 ms (to read a req.). But when you have, for example, 40 RPS (8 times more than 5 RPS), your CPU would be over-utilized by 400% and some finished requests would be waiting to be parsed, so average request time now is 50 ms + request time + *CPU wait time* + 50 ms.

To sum up, my advise would be to check a CPU utilization on both loads and, to be sure, to profile how much time does it takes to send a request and parse a response, CPU may be your bottleneck.